# Switch off laptop backlight when locking screen

Tags: lock-screen, backlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable backlight when I lock the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248972/how-can-i-disable-backlight-when-i-lock-the-screen)

I'm using an IBM Thinkpad t61 and wish to have the backlight switched off when locking the screen.I've been told to use gconf editor and un-check the backlight under `apps->gnome-power-manager`... Sounds good but the Powermanager does not appear in gconf-editor.

So I googled around with the result to use dconf-editor.

But where do I find the backlight now?