# How can I power-off the LCD on my Thinkpad?

Tags: display, monitor, thinkpad

I'm using ubuntu 12.04. When I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> on Windows the LCD turns off correctly. On Ubuntu it just puts the screen in screen saver mode.

What should I do to have the same behavior on Ubuntu as on Windows?

Comment: Relevant Qs: [Switch off laptop backlight when locking screen](http://askubuntu.com/q/99859/88802) and [How to turn off screen (DPMS) together with locking session in KDE?](http://askubuntu.com/q/189677/88802)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in shell:

```
xset dpms force off
```

If it works then [set it as a keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/249014/349837) in Gnome preferences panel.

Comment: Works, but LED that lights the keyboard (placed over the display) doesn't turn off. With a slatez (slackware based) I remember that everything functioned as windows. Do not know.

Comment: In shell works... as shortcut (FN+F3) appears "screensaver" on row of preferences panel and not works. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think You have some problem by running process `gnome-power-manager`. Try killing the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but it is not running. But killing gnome-screensaver, the problem persists, but the LED that lights the keyboard (placed over the display) turns off properly.

Comment: System -> Preferences -> Power Management.

What is your setting for "When laptop lid is closed"?

Comment: "When laptop lid is closed" --> "suspend"