# Is it possible to change a laptop's screen-dimming capabilities?

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, dv6, hp-pavilion

My laptop is able to dim it's screen automatically until it is turned off by Ubuntu to save power, currently my dim screen button doesn't let me turn off my screen completely, my questions are:

- Is it possible to configure the 'dim screen' button on a keyboard to dim the screen until it turns off or is this limited by hardware?  (I don't think that it would be limited because it can turn itself off automatically with my operating system, so why not through a key-press)
- If it is possible has someone done it or has someone got an idea of how to do it? And could they please explain it below?

If it comes in handy here's some potentially useful laptop information:

```
Model: HP Pavillion DV6000
Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS
Memory: 2Gb Ram
OS Currently Installed: Ubuntu 12.04 single-boot
```

*Edit: As suggested by the user Cumulus007 below it might be hard-coded into my hardware and not modifiable, if anyone could confirm this or find a justification for the opposite I'd be very grateful.*

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://askubuntu.com/q/134529/32063).It works for me.

Comment: It works, but however I want to be able to gradually dim the screen and then turn it off, this turns my 'Dim screen' button into a 'turn off screen' button unfortunately. Any ideas otherwise?

Comment: I think the screen dimming interval is hard-coded into either the ACPI table or the screen controller.

Comment: @Cumulus007 if you could type up your comment with sources confirming it, I'll gladly accept it as an answer :)

Comment: OP, check out [this link](http://turnyourlaptopscreenoffinlinux.blogspot.com/)

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix this question isn't version-specific. Voting to leave open

Comment: @Zanna OP flagged the question as 12.04 in both tag and in body of question. It is true screen dimming happens on all laptops and across all OS and all versions though.

Comment: That's just them adding their system information. We could post an up-to-date answer... @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @Zanna that is true someone could answer this 5 y/o question using their own OS, kernel and hardware. But it doesn't answer the question the OP had with the hardware he probably no longer has. That said my 2012 laptop doesn't dim to black with the keyboard or Ubuntu brightness slider bar either. As someone commented earlier it may just be a universal design of laptops ACPI. I use a hotkey to totally dim display: `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0`

Comment: My reasoning is @WinEunuuchs2Unix that closing this question won't cause it to be deleted, and closing has no effect on people being able to find the question through search engines. There's no benefit to closing it except massaging our stats if it doesn't help people get better search results, unless it can be closed as a duplicate (the ideal scenario here). If it remains open, there's a chance of it actually being answered and thus being useful to people searching. [Visit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) if you would like to discuss?