# How to prevent KAlarm from waking up display

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde-apps

I use KDE Plasma on a laptop with a secondary display.

When I lock the screen, [as described in this other AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189677/how-to-turn-off-screen-dpms-together-with-locking-session-in-kde/1247093#1247093) this triggers a Screen Saver notification that does a `xset dpms force off` to turn off the display.

So far, so good.

However, if a KAlarm event occurs later while the display is turned off, the external display is turned on again.

Is there a way to prevent this? I could not find a way to temporarily suspend KAlarm. There is a `--disable-all` option but no `--enable-all`?

Is there a better way than killing it and restarting it when I reconnect?

Running (K)Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, KAlarm 3.3.6 (KDE Apps 21.12.3)