# Put monitor to sleep when locked?

Tags: suspend, monitor, lock

Whenever Ubuntu 13.10 locks:

- Instead of making the monitor go black and the power button (on the monitor) turn orange like Windows did.
- It loses connection to the computer and shows me the Dell color test thing.

Can I change this?

Comment: See this if you want to turn off screen when locked http://askubuntu.com/q/248972/69051

Comment: Now, when it locks, it goes blank but the backlight is still on.